# UWP Disable default context menu but show text selection grippers

Tags: uwp, hide, contextmenu, xamarin.uwp

I added a MenuFlyout to TextBlock UI element.  I select some words in TextBlock.  Then, when I press and hold, both MenuFlyout and default Context Menu are shown.

I read somewhere to set Handled to true in ContextMenuOpening event to hide the default Context Menu.

```
private void ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

This works well.  Unfortunately, it also hide the text selection grippers on the selected text.  I would like to keep the text selection grippers on so that users can use them to change the selected text before choosing an operation from the custom Menu Flyout.  Any suggestion how to do so?  Thanks.

Comment: When Text is selected priority will be given to the default context menu. Do you want to override it and open your Menu Flyout instead of default context menu?

Comment: Yes. The above method of setting e.Handled = true hides the default context menu.  Unfortunately, it also hide the text selection grippers. (e.Handled = false shows both default context menu and text selection grippers.) My goal is to hide default context menu but show text selection grippers.  But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I tried to simulate your scenario, but setting ` e.Handled = true;` on ContextMenuOpening is hiding only context menu not the selection gripper.

Comment: [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlysZCSsfgoliNNsQ6A5hX69NFBTBQ) I am using Xamarin.UWP and the code is inside my custom renderer for Label (which is TextBlock).  I am using .NET-Standard 2.0.  Not sure these info makes any difference to its behavior.

Comment: Can you please share some XAML code, because technically even the custom context menu should not appear when `e.Handled=true` is set.

Comment: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlysZCSsfgoliNNvvvZXJ1-BFA4C_w) This is a simple Xamarin project.  (1) Use a mouse to highlight a few words. (2) Use touch on the selected text (3) Click anywhere to show the grippers.  If you repeat Steps (1) and (2), the gripper will show immediately.

Comment: [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmazyQ-ydr33hIE9j778sg2uoO6dMw) is the behavior which I am experiencing on Simulator while running your sample code when `e.Handled=true` is set. This is what you want as an expected behavior right?

Comment: Yes.  The two screenshots that I showed above are taken when I run it in "Local Machine" as well as compiled in Release mode and install on PC.  Any suggestion on how to make it display correctly with text selection gripper and no default context menu on "Local Machine" and more importantly, in installed app?

Comment: You will get selection gripper only if you are using a touch device. For pointer base input, selection gripper will not be available.

Comment: I am using a touch screen laptop.  No selection gripper.

Comment: @TekMun Just double tap the text, then the selection gripper will show aigan. Setting the `e.Handled=true` in ContextMenuOpening event handler will not affect the selection gripper to show.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, double tap the text will select the word, highlighted and show the selection gripper.  I wanted to have the same behavior (like in iOS and Android) where a user can press and hold to select some words and the customized flyout menu to appear.  I guess the recommended gesture is different on PC.